# An issue with a string paramater for a stored procedure that takes data from a load table to staging table

Tags: sql, azure, parameters, procedure

I have a stored procedure set up to take data from the load table (a table that takes data from a source csv file) to copy across to a stage table which does a number of derived fields from the load table. Basically its an azure data factory pipeline that runs:

Source File --> Load Table ---> Stage Table --> Fact Table

I have a number of "customers" who I get data from to load into the database. For each customer, there is a parameter to be declared for the stored procedure so that the database knows its for client x or y etc. 
The parameters are just string text like 'customer1', 'customer2' etc.

I have a new customer dataset to be loaded into the database and I've simply decided to call it 'customer3'. However for some reason the stored procedure doesn't recognise this parameter. When the SP is executed with the 'customer3' parameter, the stage table is simply blank rather than populated with data from the load table.

Why is it coming up with a blank staging table?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the stored procedure is taking  parameter as  customer and the reading the data from the load table and then inserts into the staging table . Are  passing the parameter @Customer to the pipeline , if yes is it getting passed to the proc ?  Is the data getting loaded in to the load table , if yes , then please open SQL Server management , connect to the DB try to

`EXECUTE YourPeocName @Yourparametername='customer3'`

and see if it does the load the stage table , it it does that  means that the proc is doing what its should and the issue is on passing the paramter to the proc in the pipeline .

Let me know how it goes .